# Solving the inequality $-1<\frac{2}{x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> What is the range of $x$ for inequality $-1<\frac{2}{x}$ ?

My attempt is as follows:

$$-1<\frac{2}{x}$$

$$-1\cdot{x}<2$$

Multiplying by $-1$ on both sides, which changes sign, we get:

$$x>-2$$

So according to this resultant equation lets put some value of x into the first equation.

Let's take $x=-1$

$$-1<\frac{2}{-1}$$

$$-1<-2$$

I am not able to understand what is wrong here, why am I getting contradictory result when I put values of $x$ in the original question.

Comment: When you multiply $x$ on both sides, something may go wrong. One needs to be carful with the sign of $x$.

Comment: but its a very basic thing in math, which we are allowed to do.

Comment: No. From $-1<\frac{2}{x}$ to $-1\cdot x<2$, you are assuming that $x$ is positive. If $x$ is negative, this is not true. Note that $-1<\frac{2}{-3}$ but $-1\cdot(-3)>2$.

Comment: @user3290550: When you multiply by $x$, you are implicitly assuming the sign of $x$ (positive or negative). You have to handle it in cases: one where $x$ is positive, and one where $x$ is negative.

Comment: @Jack ,but still while solving long or heavy inequations, one can do this mistake very easily, so how to avoid this in competitions where we have less time.

Comment: [There is no royal road.](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Euclid#Attributed) `:)`

Comment: Your mistake is on multiplying the inequality by $x$ *blindly*.

Answer (score 3):

For $x>0$ we get $$-x<2$$ so $$x>-2$$
For $$x<0$$ we get $$-x>2$$ so $$x<-2$$

Answer (score 0):

The following step

$$-1<\frac{2}{x} \implies -1\cdot{x}<\frac{2}{x}\cdot{x}=2$$

is correct ony for $x>0$.

Otherwise we need to reverse the inequality sign.

Answer (score 0):

$$-1<\dfrac2x\iff\dfrac{x+2}x>0$$

$\iff x(x+2)>0$

$\implies x>$max$(0,-2)$

Or $x<$min$(0,-2)$

Answer (score 0):

We can multiply both sides by $x^2$ since $x^2 \geq 0$, so the sign won't change after multiplying both sides by $x^2$.

$$\begin{aligned}
-1 &< \frac{2}{x}\\
-x^2 &< 2x\\
x^2 + 2x &> 0\\
x(x+2) &> 0\\
x > 0, &\quad x < -2
\end{aligned}$$

Therefore, the range of solutions is $x \in (-\infty, -2) \cup (0, \infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way: $$\frac{2}{x} >-1 \Rightarrow \frac{2}{x}+1>0 \Rightarrow \frac{x+2}{x} >0 \Rightarrow x(x+2)>0 \Rightarrow x<-2~or~x>0$$

Answer (score 0):

When you go from

$-1 < \frac{2}{x}$

to

$-x < 2$,

you're assuming that $x$ is positive since multiplication by a negative number flips the inequality sign. So when you have $x = -1$(or simply $x < 0$), you will have 
 $-x > 2$ instead of $-x < 2$.

Answer (score -1):

THE GIVEN INEQUALITY HAS GOT RANGE AS X<-2 AND X>=0.
Reason for it is 
                          2/X >-1.
                         Implies two cases 1) if 2/X >0.
                                                               Implies X>=0
                                                           2)if -1<2/X<0.
                                                               Implies X<-2.

Comment: May I know the reason for downvote

Comment: Just because one has downvoted are others downvoting it

Comment: It is simply devasting

Comment: If this is the case no one will put answers further

Comment: How can you delete my answer.Is this the way you give respect to the users. Absolutely unsatisfied. Change your mind set.If you don't like the answer tell the user what is fault.Simply deleting the post makes no sense.Did every one get that.